# Select all files which are a child of a folder and it subfolders in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Okay, so I have a structure which can look like this

```
d
├── a
│   ├── f_2
│   └── f_3
├── b
│   ├── f
│   │   └── f_5
│   └── f_4
├── c
└── f_1
```

But there can be a lot of sub-folders and files. However, in the database they are stored as: `(id, parent_id, type, name)` where type is the file/folders id, parent_id is the parent folder, type tells if the entry is a file or folder, and name is an ASCII  string representing the name of the folder/file.

What I want to do is being able to give an id of any folder in the tree, let us say in this case `d` and I want to select ids of all files and folder which are children of the folder `d` include their sub children.

I have looked through the mySQL documentation on hierarchical structures but I cannot see a solution based on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @Shadow this is not a duplicate of that question, the question only ask for single level children, which my question does not. So I disagree that this is a duplicate as it cannot be solved in the same manner

Comment: @LarsNielsen nope, you misread the duplicate question. The level of hierarchy is undefined, can be any. There are several answers that handle unlimited levels of hierarchy.